# Menu items missing in Ubuntu Videos, Files, Transmission,

Tags: 16.04, menu

Menu items do not pop up in Videos (default app that plays videos) and Files and many other apps. This  happened after reboot in 16.04 lts.

When I hover with the mouse it just displays the minimize/maximize/close buttons.

PS. I should clarify: Menus are available for some other applications, such as VLC, Chrome,...

Actually, it seems to me that this only affects the default apps that were initially installed, and not the ones added later (such as vlc, chrome).

PS. After a reboot, everything is back to normal. :)

Comment: likely this known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532226. Workaround: `restart unity-panel-service`

Comment: thank you. that seems to be it. no big deal, just annoying.